# What is $previous is in this line of code in /etc/init.d/ssh

Tags: 18.04, scripts

I will just be supplying the one line. Neither $previous nor $runlevel is defined before this. I can imagine what $runlevel is but how does $previous work here?

```
run_by_init() {
    ( [ "$previous" ] && [ "$runlevel" ]) || [ "$runlevel" = S]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And where did you obtain this file?

Comment: @ElderGeek it's in the title. /etc/init.d/ssh  . I assumed every ubuntu machine had this script. Am I incorrect in doing so?

Comment: It doesn't exist on a fresh install of 18.04 which the tags indicate is the version you have, nor does it exist on 16.04.

Comment: @ElderGeek I can assure you I am on 18.04 and it is indeed here. I'll have to see who put this on here then. I know everything for startups is now used with systemd but I was told to continue using init.d files. Thank you

Comment: @ElderGeek The OP has `openssh-server` installed... that's where this file comes from.

Comment: @Ravexina That is correct. Do you happen to know what the $previous variable means? I don't see any declaring of "previous" in the code. Is this a ubuntu or linux built in term?

Comment: @UCProgrammer I guess it's related to RUNLEVELS, it might contain the previous runlevel id. I'm not sure.

Comment: The line you've provided has a typo. The file you refer to in openssh-server package `run_by_init()`, not `run_by_it()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$previous is defined in `/etc/init.d/rc` on line 49
as previous=$PREVLEVEL and refers to the previous run level.